# Magento 2 - Where is the value of locale in Magento system?

Tags: magento2, locale

In Magento 2, Where is the value of locale in Magento system? Ex: from database or machine, or some place.

In file: Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getDateFormat($type = \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT)
    {
        return (new \IntlDateFormatter(
            $this->_localeResolver->getLocale(),
            $type,
            \IntlDateFormatter::NONE
        ))->getPattern();
    }
```

> focus this line: **$this->_localeResolver->getLocale()**

Answer (score 1):

Locale stored in system config (table `core_config_data`):

[image: data]

By default the locale is set in the `Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver::getDefaultLocale()`:

```
public function getDefaultLocale()
{
    if (!$this->defaultLocale) {
        $locale = $this->scopeConfig->getValue($this->getDefaultLocalePath(), $this->scopeType);
        if (!$locale) {
            $locale = self::DEFAULT_LOCALE;
        }
        $this->defaultLocale = $locale;
    }
    return $this->defaultLocale;
}
```

For receiving the current locale use `Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver::getLocale()`.

Comment: I've just post related this question? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113006/magento-2-why-before-function-param-is-null-and-then-get-value-of-param-in-f