# Magento 2 - Why before function param is null , and then get value of param in func has value?

Tags: magento2, locale

In Magento 2, Why before function param is null , and then get value of param in func has value?

I get value before:

[image]

I get value in function:

[image]

And result:

[image]

Comment: I have checked it in the debug and there is [no value](https://gyazo.com/bcf2c16610bd8b4345de6c4643c6d2f6)

Comment: Where was no value? at "before" or "after"

Comment: In both cases is null

Comment: Do you think, what which case happen above problem ?

Comment: Some plug-in is perhaps used. Try to search in the project the "beforeSetLocale" string (method name).